# Cannot open this QML document because of an error in the QML file

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

When I create a new project in Qt Creator using the "Qt Quick Application - Empty" as a template.

I get an error when I want to go to design:

> 'Cannot open this QML document because of an error in the QML file'

I already tried to reinstall Qt Creator but it didn't work.

I'm using Qt Creator 4.11.1 with QT 5.14.1

Cannot open this QML document because of an error in the QML file

And I'm using cmake instead of qmake.

[image]

This is the qml code:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

This is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(simple_qml LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)

add_executable(simple_qml
  main.cpp
  qml.qrc
)

target_compile_definitions(simple_qml
  PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(simple_qml
  PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick)
```

Comment: before you go to design you need to go to "File -->New File or Project --> Qt --> QtQuick UI File"

Comment: show the qml content: press "Edit".

Comment: I just create an ui file but I still have the same problem. I don't know what to do.

Comment: `import QtQuick 2.4  Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400
}`

Comment: `import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
`